# How can I split words by the second tab for MapReduce?

Tags: java, string, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm doing MapReduces on some web data.  (I'm new to MapReduce, so think classic WordCount type stuff.)  The input file is as follows, numbers followed by a tabs:

3 2 2 4 2 2 2 3 3

While I understand how to get a classic 'word count' of the numbers, what I really want to do is evaluate the numbers in pairs, so the above would be read by the mapper as '3 2', '2 2', '2 4', '2 2', and so on.  How do I do this?  I suppose all that's necessary is to tweak the StringTokenizer to split words by second tab or something, but how would I do that?  Is that even possible?

Here's the Java code I'm working with, which, as of now is just the classic WordCount example in MapReduce:

```
public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!  This ended up being the solution I came up with (after adding some leading zeroes to help with formatting):

```
 public class WordCount {

   public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         String data = value.toString();
         for (int i = 0; i < (data.length() / 3) - 1; i++) {
             String pair = data.substring(i*3, (i*3)+5);
             context.write(new Text(pair), one);
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify the WordCount to have your expected behavior.

```
public static class TokenizerMapper 
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    String myString = word.toString();
    String [] numbers = myString.split("\t"); // split by tab
    if (numbers.length> 2)
    {
        // you need at least two numbers to make one pair
        int first = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        int second;
        for (int i=1; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        {
           second = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
           Text keynew = new Text(first+"\t"+second);
           context.write(keynew, one);
           // your second will be the first in the next loop iteration
           first = second;
        }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, had some small errors, so I corrected them and then ran it, but it actually doesn't write anything.  Any idea why?

Comment: @user3222006 try to change the data type of the "first" and "second" variables to String and remove the parseInt (there might be something that is not a number in the data...), and also make sure the tab is delimiter.

Comment: @user3222006 BTW the script does generate the _SUCCESS file in the output folder? right?

Comment: I don't know, can't really access the output folder, says there's nothing in there?  However, this shows up: "15/02/28 14:39:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local619852621_0001 completed successfully" and then has the run-down of how many bytes were written, etc.  

I also tried changing the variables to String, but no dice, unfortunately.  Any other ideas?  Thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: Normally, the "bytes written" and "bytes read" portions at the very bottom of the mapreduce output let me know 'okay, so it read the file successfully', and 'okay, it didn't manage to write anything':

15/02/28 14:39:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/02/28 14:39:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local619852621_0001 completed successfully...
 ...File Input Format Counters 
  Bytes Read=12581691
 File Output Format Counters 
  Bytes Written=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String data = "0\t0\t1\t2\t4\t5\t3\t4\t6\t7";
String[] array = data.split("(?<=\\G\\w{1,3}\t\\w{1,3})\t");

    for(String s : array){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

where {1,3} is the range for number of digits in a number.

Output:

```
 0  0

 1  2

 4  5

 3  4

 6  7
```

For your code,

```
String[] pairsArray = value.toString().split("(?<=\\G\\w{1,3}\t\\w{1,3})\t");
for (String pair : pairsArray) {
     context.write(new Text(pair), one);
}
```

Comment: I mean I understand how to split strings on tabs, in a vacuum, I guess the larger problem here is how to integrate that into all MapReduce's classes and iterators.  Like where does it all go?

Comment: You can use it your map tasks. Like value.toString().split... Special thing about this code snippet is its regex which splits string by second tab which you wanted. Now you can iterate the array of pairs in your code. Let me know if you want anything else.

Comment: That's the thing, though.  value.toString().split doesn't compile, get an error like this: WordCount.java:26: error: no suitable constructor found for StringTokenizer(String[])
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString().split("(?<=\\G\\w{1,3}\t\\w{1,3})\t"));

It appears that the StringTokenizer actually takes a string array, which is confusing to me, because anything that takes the .toString() argument should thereafter be a string, right?  I'm real confused here

Comment: You are not suppose to use StringTokenizer. I've modified the code. Check it out.

Comment: This ended up being very helpful.  Ultimately, I had to dispense with .split(), as I was looking for overlapping substrings, but realizing that I wasn't beholden to the StringTokenizer was the key.  Thanks a lot.